# San Francisco traffic lights green/yellow/red timings

Tags: usa, traffic

Where would one go about finding data for traffic lights?

For example, scheduled timings as well as actual (historical) timings.

(San Francisco)

Comment: To be clear, you are not looking for latitude/longitude of the traffic lights (which can be found on OpenStreetMap), but only for when each light was/will be green/yellow/red, right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, Yepp, I need it to produce (very) accurate traffic predictions.

Answer (score 2):

[Traffic Technology Services](https://www.traffictechservices.com/) provides live traffic light status (red, yellow , green, etc...) data.  For San Francisco, it might be available via https://datasf.org/

Comment: The page <https://data.sfgov.org/Transportation/Map-of-Traffic-Signals/9d64-i7fs> is missing status info/logs